# React onClick not firing es6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have searched this question but no solution has worked for me. I know the function is registered properly because if I do something like onClick={this.searchSolutions()} then the console.log shows up on page load. It is just the onClick portion that is not working.

```
import React from 'react';

class QueryForm extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.searchSolutions = this.searchSolutions.bind(this);
  }

  searchSolutions() {
    console.log("button clicked");
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="queryForm">
        <h1 className="lead"></h1>
        <div className="form-group">
          <label for="solutionQuery">Search by solution:</label>
          <input type="text" className="form-control" id="solutionQuery" placeholder="Enter solution name" />
          <button type="button" className="btn btn-outline btn-primary" onClick={this.searchSolutions}>Search</button>
        </div>
        <div id="results">

        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

module.exports = QueryForm;
```

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me, you do have a problem with using `for` in the label element (it should be `htmlFor`). That could be what is causing your problem, depending on how you have your environment set up.

[Here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/77219/) with that fix and the method running as expected.

Answer (score -1):

your problem is that you were using `this.searchSolutions()`. Doing it like this will run the function as soon as it is read (so whenever that element is first rendered). Using just `this.searchSolutions` (without the `()`) will fix your problem.

Comment: I was referring to when he said *if I do something like onClick={this.searchSolutions()}*. I assumed that he had made changes between the time in which he wrote the text, and the time in which he posted the code snippet (which would explain why his code now works).

Comment: Yeah sorry for the confusion, I just said that to demonstrate that the function could work if I run it that way. It's not how I am normally using it.